# Stored Procedure gets published encrypted

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sqlclr, sqlproj

So I made a simple stored procedure with SQLCLR and published it to my database. There are already some SPs and they are all not encrypted, only my published SP is encrypted. I googled for hours but could not find out how to turn the encryption off. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLCLR object is not encrypted. In fact, encryption is not even an option for SQLCLR objects. The issue (i.e. why SSMS and Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer indicate that SQLCLR objects are encrypted) is that there is no definition of the object in `sys.sql_modules` (since their definition is in the Assembly and is not T-SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I figured out that all the SP does is to reference the SP method in the assembly. My Problem was that I couldn't debug my code. I thought it was because the SP was "encrypted". I should have run VS as Admin and "Allow SQL/CLR Debugging" in SQL Server Object Explorer. Took some Google-Fu to figure that out.

Comment: @Siggi Glad you figured that part out. If my answer answers the question that you posted (not dealing with debugging), then please don't forget to mark as accepted :). Thanks.